# d3 chart won't centre in UIkit framework

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, layout, uikit

I have designed a chart using d3.js and have embedded it in a div within a UIkit framework, however I can't get it to centre within the div.

I have tried putting the svg in a container and adjusting the CSS by putting the svg in a flexbox, removing the margins, aligning it centre, but none of it works. I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49278757/d3-map-not-centering-on-page) response, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639383/how-do-i-center-an-svg-in-a-div/44963267#44963267) one, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13373169/align-svg-to-center-of-screen) one and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49278757/d3-map-not-centering-on-page) one and none of them work. I'm sure it must be something simple - how can I get it to centre? Code below.

Chart

```
<div id="age_chart" class="uk-container uk-width-medium-1-2 uk-container-center uk-margin-top">
  <script>
  // chart based on this example: https://bl.ocks.org/63anp3ca/6bafeb64181d87750dbdba78f8678715
  // var svg1 = d3.select("svg1"),
  var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 100, left: 20},
      width1 = d3.select("#age_chart").node().getBoundingClientRect().width,
      height1 = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
      // g = svg1.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  // The scale spacing the groups:
  var x0 = d3.scaleBand()
      .rangeRound([0, width1])
      .paddingInner(0.05);

  // The scale for spacing each group's bar:
  var x1 = d3.scaleBand()
      .padding(0.05);

  var y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .rangeRound([height1, 0]);

  var z = d3.scaleOrdinal()
      .range(["#2c7fb8", "#7fcdbb"]);

    var svg1 = d3.select('body').append("svg")
    .attr("width", width1 + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height1 + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  d3.csv("data/age_distribution.csv", function(d, i, columns) {
      for (var i = 1, n = columns.length; i < n; ++i) d[columns[i]] = +d[columns[i]];
      return d;
  }).then(function(data) {
      console.log(data);

      var keys = data.columns.slice(1);

      console.log('keys');
      console.log(keys);
      x0.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.age; }));
      x1.domain(keys).rangeRound([0, x0.bandwidth()]);
      y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d3.max(keys, function(key) { return d[key]; }); })]).nice();

      svg1.append("g")
          .selectAll("g")
          .data(data)
          .enter().append("g")
          .attr("class","bar")
          .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.age) + ",0)"; })
          .selectAll("rect")
          .data(function(d) { return keys.map(function(key) { return {key: key, value: d[key]}; }); })
          .enter().append("rect")
          .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.key); })
          .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
          .attr("width", x1.bandwidth())
          .attr("height", function(d) { return height1 - y(d.value); })
          .attr("fill", function(d) { return z(d.key); });

      svg1.append("g")
          .attr("class", "axis")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height1 + ")")
          .call(d3.axisBottom(x0));

      svg1.append("g")
          .attr("class", "y axis")
          .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(null, "s"))
          .append("text")
          .attr("x", 2)
          .attr("y", y(y.ticks().pop()) + 0.5)
          .attr("dy", "0.32em")
          .attr("fill", "#000")
          .attr("font-size", 11)
          .attr("text-anchor", "start")
          .text("Percentage of population")
          .attr("font-family", "Archivo");

      var legend1 = svg1.append("g")
          .attr("font-family", "inherit")
          .attr("font-size", 11)
          .attr("text-anchor", "end")
          .selectAll("g")
          .data(keys.slice().reverse())
          .enter().append("g")
          .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

      legend1.append("rect")
          .attr("x", width1 * .9)
          .attr("width", 15)
          .attr("height", 15)
          .attr("fill", z)
          .attr("stroke", z)
          .attr("stroke-width",2)
          .on("click",function(d) { update(d) });

      legend1.append("text")
          .attr("x", width1 * .85)
          .attr("y", 9.5)
          .attr("dy", "0.32em")
          .text(function(d) { return d; });

      var filtered = [];

      ////
      //// Update and transition on click:
      ////

      function update(d) {

          //
          // Update the array to filter the chart by:
          //

          // add the clicked key if not included:
          if (filtered.indexOf(d) == -1) {
              filtered.push(d);
              // if all bars are un-checked, reset:
              if(filtered.length == keys.length) filtered = [];
          }
          // otherwise remove it:
          else {
              filtered.splice(filtered.indexOf(d), 1);
          }

          //
          // Update the scales for each group's items:
          //
          var newKeys = [];
          keys.forEach(function(d) {
              if (filtered.indexOf(d) == -1 ) {
                  newKeys.push(d);
              }
          })
          x1.domain(newKeys).rangeRound([0, x0.bandwidth()]);
          y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d3.max(keys, function(key) { if (filtered.indexOf(key) == -1) return d[key]; }); })]).nice();

          // update the y axis:
          svg1.select(".y")
              .transition()
              .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(null, "s"))
              .duration(500);


          //
          // Filter out the bands that need to be hidden:
          //
          var bars = svg1.selectAll(".bar").selectAll("rect")
              .data(function(d) { return keys.map(function(key) { return {key: key, value: d[key]}; }); })

          bars.filter(function(d) {
                  return filtered.indexOf(d.key) > -1;
              })
              .transition()
              .attr("x", function(d) {
                  return (+d3.select(this).attr("x")) + (+d3.select(this).attr("width"))/2;
              })
              .attr("height",0)
              .attr("width",0)
              .attr("y", function(d) { return height1; })
              .duration(500);

          //
          // Adjust the remaining bars:
          //
          bars.filter(function(d) {
                  return filtered.indexOf(d.key) == -1;
              })
              .transition()
              .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.key); })
              .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
              .attr("height", function(d) { return height1 - y(d.value); })
              .attr("width", x1.bandwidth())
              .attr("fill", function(d) { return z(d.key); })
              .duration(500);


          // update legend:
          legend1.selectAll("rect")
              .transition()
              .attr("fill",function(d) {
                  if (filtered.length) {
                      if (filtered.indexOf(d) == -1) {
                          return z(d);
                      }
                      else {
                          return "white";
                      }
                  }
                  else {
                      return z(d);
                  }
              })
              .duration(100);
      }

  });
  </script>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the SVG isn't in your div.

The position of a `script` element doesn't decide where the SVG will get appended on the page. If you put it at the bottom of the page, you'll get the same results - you need to do so to wait for the DOM to be fully loaded.

`d3.select('body').append("svg")` will append the svg directly on the `body` element. To append it to the element you've created, since it has id `age_chart`, use:

```
d3.select('#age_chart').append("svg")
```

Comment: That has centred it, thank you! But the legend has now disappeared, do you know what might have caused that? Nothing's coming up when I debug it